# Modal popup behind keyboard

Tags: ios, ios7, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal popup which is placed behind the keyboard.

How can I move the modal popup to a higher position?

[image]

Comment: is it a modal view controller? can you illustrate with a screenshot? If you just want to move UITextFields or whatever that are subViews of your modalView controller, then you can listen for a keyboardDidShow notification and set the textField frames as required.

Comment: Hi, yes this is a modal view controller with freeform. I want to move the complete modal view up, so you can see the complete login form. The strange thing is: I use [userText becomeFirstResponder]; the keyboard is over the modal. If I hide the keyboard, and bring it back up, the modal is positioned correctly... I now have the becomeFirstResonder in the -(void)viewWillAppear method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is work around to get rid of mentioned situation.

I assume you are using `becomeFirstResponder` for textField. Write below code in class which is presented modally.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self performSelector:@selector(txtFieldResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

-(void)txtFieldResponder{
    [self.txt becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had it already with a delayed selector, so I think this is a work around for this issue. So that's why I accepted your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

Register class for keyboard show and hide notification

```
NSNotificationCenter        *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(showKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(hideKeyboard:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

Then implement

```
- (void)showKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification {

//Change popup frame here 
}


- (void)hideKeyboard:(NSNotification *)notification {
//Change popup frame to previous state 

}
```